# model's dependency data to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 dependent models and my project

```
public class EditPaymentMethodModel
{
    public PaymentMethodViewData PaymentViewData { get; set; }
    public BillingAddressModel BillingAddresses { get; set; }
    public CspacModel NewBillingAddress { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentMethodViewData 
{
    public int? PaymentMethodId { get; set; }
}

public class CreditCardViewData : PaymentMethodViewData
{
     public string CardNumber { get; set; }
     ....
     ....
     ....
     [ViagogoCpfCnpj(CardNoProperty = "CardNumber")]
     public string CpfOrCnpj { get; set; }
}
```

1. **PaymentMethodViewData** is the parent of all payment methods.
2. **CreditCardViewData** is inherited by PaymentMethodViewModel.
3. **EditPaymentMethodModel** is my views model.

PaymentMethodViewData actually does not have any CreditCardViewData, however we have payment method handler and it is adding creditcardviewdata to paymentmethodviewdata after this line

```
var paymentMethodViewData = PaymentMethodHandler.GetPaymentMethodData(payment, userId);
```

finally I have a view and its model is EditPaymentMethodModel

```
@model Viagogo.Mvc.OM.Pipeline.BuyPipeline.EditPaymentMethodModel
```

**What I want to do is, if payment type is credit card I just want to do is line below, however currently it gives an error and I could not figure it out**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PaymentViewData.CreditCardViewData.CpfOrCnpj)
```

EDIT 1 : ERROR IS AT RUNTIME

Comment: Give me 5 minutes, I have 5 min cache time to build the project @Exception

Comment: Is your payment method handler setting the property `PaymentViewData` to type of `CreditCardViewData`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes exactly, but the problem is, I dont have any idea about dependency injenction. Although I dont have creditcardviewdata property on PaymentMethodViewData, it could set it

Comment: Obviously modifying your view model is best. Is there a reason you cant do that? If not I can post an answer but its a bit ugly

Comment: @StephenMuecke the reason is I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cant change `public PaymentMethodViewData PaymentViewData { get; set; }` to `public CreditCardViewData PaymentViewData { get; set; }` then you could add an additional property to the view model - something like

```
public class EditPaymentMethodModel
{
  ....
  [ViagogoCpfCnpj(CardNoProperty = "CardNumber")]
  public string CpfOrCnpj
  {
    get
    {
      if (PaymentViewData != null && PaymentViewData is CreditCardViewData)
      {
        return ((CreditCardViewData)PaymentViewData).CpfOrCnpj;
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

which you can access in the view with

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PaymentViewData.CreditCardViewData.CpfOrCnpj)
```

However this property has no setter, so the ModelBinder will not set any value for `CpfOrCnpj`.  If you need this value in the post method, you would need to get it from the `FormCollection`